# Appcenter Android Build for React-Native with Unity

Tags: react-native, unity-game-engine, android-build, visual-studio-app-center, automated-deployment

I am working on a React-Native project using Unity (asmadsen/react-native-unity-view). The code is working properly on both Android and iOS and build is also being generated for both the platforms respectively. But now I am trying to make the build through Appcenter for Android doing all the necessary setup process but it's failing all the time. But when I am doing the same for a demo React-Native project, the build is successful on the Appcenter.

The error logs as found on the Appcenter is :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/runner/work/1/s/android/UnityExport/unityLibrary/build.gradle' line: 66

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':UnityExport:BuildIl2CppTask'.
> Location specified by ndk.dir (/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.3.16f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/NDK) did not contain a valid NDK and couldn't be used

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 56s
```

Can anyone has any idea and help me over the same. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's seem that you haven't valid NDK on your computer, for unity 2018 you must install **android-ndk-r16b** and for unity 2020 you must install **android-ndk-r19**.

depend on your OS and unity version download and install valid NDK from [NDK](https://github.com/android/ndk/wiki/Unsupported-Downloads).

Comment: Thanks for ur help. But can u let me know how I could install the ndk on Appcenter. I googled it as well but didn't found anything.

Comment: only extract it and in unity **Edit> Preferences... > External Tools ** change the NDK path to extracted folder